# Excel - deleting space from numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset that I've copy pasted into Excel and some numbers have spaces between them. This is subset of a column in the spreadsheet:

[image]

As you can see in the 3rd, 4th, 5th, 9th and 10th rows there's some space between the characters that I want to delete.

Are there any good formulas here for this? I've tried the TRIM-function a couple times but it's only useable for strings. And a complementary note is that they are all treated as generals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Highlight the range that you want to modify
2. CTRL + F
3. Click Replace
4. "Find what: " (put a blank space here so it searches for spaces)
5. "Replace with: " (leave this blank)
6. Click Replace all, and the selected range should search for blank spaces and replace them with nothing

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions you can use for replacing a character in a string: `Replace()` and `Substitute()`:

- `Replace()` can be used when you know **where** you want to replace **whatever**.
- `Substitute()` can be used if you know **exactly what** you want to replace **anywhere**.

So, in this case:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C2," ","")
```

Answer (score 1):

`=NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A10," ",""))` replaces the space and returns a number

Answer (score 0):

yea firstly select the column and you can use 'Text to Column' which is under the 'Data' menu bar.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehn0p.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).